# Change hyphen symbol to number in Spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets

If A2=10,B2=2 means A2 higher than B2 result will get result "Good", but how if A2 is symbol "-" ?

How can I change "-" to "0" inside this Google Spreadsheet formula?

```
=IF(AND(A2>=B2), "Good")
```

I find this formula but no idea how to combine with above formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","0")
```

Here my spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIpOA2bgh_00nNW70pMy4FBruRzdhOtRXFQrAb-PJTc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for anyone who willing help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap out the A2 in the first formula with `--SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",0)`, ie

```
=IF(AND(--SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",0)>=B2), "Good")
```

The -- converts the `SUBSTITUTE` result to a number. We need this or it will be a string after `SUBSTITUTE`, and the comparison won't work like you expect. Note that this will convert any number of `-`s to 0, not just a single one.

I kept the `AND` because I assume you want to add more to it later.

Comment: Thank you, it's work but I put , after "Good" to get blank result
=IF(AND(--SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",0)>=B2), "Good", )